# How to do a SQL INSERT of a timestamp in new column of table with cast to data type DATETIME

Tags: mysql, datetime, casting, insert

I have a table with a column 'TIMESTAMP' of data type VARCHAR:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ID` int, `TIMESTAMP` varchar(24), `TOPIC` varchar(30), `PAYLOAD` numeric, `UNIT` varchar(5), `SENSOR` varchar(25), `DerivedValue` int, `DerivedValueDesc` varchar(17))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ID`, `TIMESTAMP`, `TOPIC`, `PAYLOAD`, `UNIT`, `SENSOR`, `DerivedValue`, `DerivedValueDesc`)
VALUES
    (17463, '2019-11-28T17:58:12.776Z', 'Wago-855-9150', 475.29334, 'W', '"Wago 855-9150/2000-0701"', 1, '"Produktion ja"'),
    (17464, '2019-11-28T17:58:13.675Z', 'ifm-O5D150', 19.0625, 'cm', '"ifm O5D150"', 1, '"Tür offen"'),
    (17465, '2019-11-28T17:58:13.675Z', 'Keyence-FD-Q20C', 0, 'L/min', '"Keyence FD-Q20C"', 0, '"Durchfluss nein"'),
    (17466, '2019-11-28T17:58:14.676Z', 'ifm-O5D150', 23.0625, 'cm', '"ifm O5D150"', 0, '"Tür zu"'),
    (17467, '2019-11-28T17:58:14.676Z', 'Keyence-FD-Q20C', 0, 'L/min', '"Keyence FD-Q20C"', 0, '"Durchfluss nein"'),
    (17468, '2019-11-28T17:58:14.776Z', 'Wago-855-9150', 569.14666, 'W', '"Wago 855-9150/2000-0701"', 1, '"Produktion ja"')
;
```

It turns out now that querying the table is very time consuming:

```
SELECT PAYLOAD FROM Table1 WHERE TOPIC LIKE '%temperature%' AND CAST(TIMESTAMP AS datetime) between '2019-09-29 00:00:00' and '2019-09-29 00:59:59';
```

So the idea is to create an additional column and store right there the timestamp in data type DATETIME:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD `DATETIME` DATETIME AFTER `TIMESTAMP`;
```

Then I want to fill the new column with the converted data from the column TIMESTAMP:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(DATETIME) SELECT CAST(`TIMESTAMP` AS DATETIME) FROM Table1;
```

Then i get the error message:

> Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Truncated incorrect datetime value:
> '2019-11-28T17:58:12.776Z'

I get this error while prototyping the query in https://www.db-fiddle.com/ and http://sqlfiddle.com/. I am using an MySQL database v5.7.

Interestingly this query works:

```
SELECT `TIMESTAMP`, CAST(`TIMESTAMP` AS DATETIME) AS `MYDATETIME` FROM Table1;
```

But i need the data in the new column not in a query.

What is my mistake? I think it is better not to take string operations like STR_TO_DATE because of uncertain consquences to the rounding of the seconds.

Comment: Yes for new data recordings, i will create a new table with a column of data type DATETIME. But I want to keep the existing recorded data and therefore I want to convert the existing timestamp.

Comment: _Small note_ `\`PAYLOAD\` numeric,` is also causing truncation when you load that data as `numeric` converts to `decimal(10,0)`

Comment: Also might be worth checking if its a good idea storing the double quotes in the `SENSOR` and `DerivedValueDesc` columns

Comment: The numeric 'PAYLOAD' comes from the Text-to-DLL import at DB Fiddle. It's double in the real database. The double quotes i haven't noticed yet, thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only part that disagrees with MySQL's [date literal format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) is the `'Z'` at the end.

```
mysql> select cast('2019-11-28T17:58:12.776Z' as datetime);
+----------------------------------------------+
| cast('2019-11-28T17:58:12.776Z' as datetime) |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 2019-11-28 17:58:13                          |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2019-11-28T17:58:12.776Z'
```

But trimming the `'Z'` makes it okay:

```
mysql> select cast(trim(trailing 'Z' from '2019-11-28T17:58:12.776Z') as datetime);
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cast(trim(trailing 'Z' from '2019-11-28T17:58:12.776Z') as datetime) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-11-28 17:58:13                                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want to preserve the milliseconds, then cast to `datetime(3)`:

```
mysql> select cast(trim(trailing 'Z' from '2019-11-28T17:58:12.776Z') as datetime(3));
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cast(trim(trailing 'Z' from '2019-11-28T17:58:12.776Z') as datetime(3)) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-11-28 17:58:12.776                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I almost got it right with INSERT INTO Table1(DATETIME) SELECT cast(trim(trailing 'Z' from `TIMESTAMP`) as datetime) FROM Table1; But the INSERT creates new rows and does not fill the existing rows. My SQL skills are too limited.

Comment: So far i can fill a second table with the new column of type datetime with: INSERT INTO Table2(DATETIME,TOPIC,ID,PAYLOAD,UNIT,SENSOR,DerivedValue,DerivedValueDesc) SELECT cast(trim(trailing 'Z' from `TIMESTAMP`) as datetime),TOPIC,ID,PAYLOAD,UNIT,SENSOR,DerivedValue,DerivedValueDesc FROM Table1; This is great also then i can keep the old table untouched...

Comment: Yes, INSERT creates new rows. You might consider [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) or [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) but if your insert/replace statements are generating new auto-increment id's, then that won't help because new inserts naturally won't be duplicates.

Comment: Yes, you're right with the auto-increment id's! So i accepted your answer. Thank you very much once again.